# GNU indent: How to forbid inserting newlines before `,' in declaration of struct arrays?

Tags: indentation, indent

See following example. I don't want the `,` char in a separate line. I go through all `indent` options but seems like no one is for this.

```
$ indent -version
GNU indent 2.2.9
$ cat foo.c
void
foo ()
{
  struct_a arr[] = {
    {&a, sizeof (a)},
    {&b, sizeof (b)},
    {&c, sizeof (c)},
    {&d, sizeof (d)},
  };
}
$ indent -st foo.c
void
foo ()
{
  struct_a arr[] = {
    {&a, sizeof (a)}
    ,
    {&b, sizeof (b)}
    ,
    {&c, sizeof (c)}
    ,
    {&d, sizeof (d)}
    ,
  };
}
$
```

Comment: Which Linux version?

Comment: The OS version does not matter for me. I'm using `GNU indent 2.2.9`. I can compile the latest version of indent if that would help.

Comment: You might need to go into the sources to find out why `-nbc` does not work as recommended by @DavidPostill.

Comment: `-[n]bc` only affects the var names as in `int a, b, c;`. It does not affect the initialization code as in `= { ... };`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's `sizeof()` that confused `indent`. So I have a workaround: First, change all occurrences of `sizeof` with `SIZEOF` (e.g. using `sed`), then invoke `indent`, and then change `SIZEOF` back to `sizeof`.

```
$ cat foo.c
void foo() {
    struct_a arr[] = {
        {&a, sizeof (a), 1},
        {&b, sizeof (b), 1},
        {&c, sizeof (c), 1},
        {&d, sizeof (d), 1},
    };
}
$ indent -st foo.c
void
foo ()
{
  struct_a arr[] = {
    {&a, sizeof (a), 1}
    ,
    {&b, sizeof (b), 1}
    ,
    {&c, sizeof (c), 1}
    ,
    {&d, sizeof (d), 1}
    ,
  };
}
$ sed s/sizeof/SIZEOF/g foo.c | indent -st | sed s/SIZEOF/sizeof/g
void
foo ()
{
  struct_a arr[] = {
    {&a, sizeof (a), 1},
    {&b, sizeof (b), 1},
    {&c, sizeof (c), 1},
    {&d, sizeof (d), 1},
  };
}
$
```

Comment: I must say that this sounds very unlikely. The problem is probably more general than that.

Comment: I'm not sure. You can try it.

Answer (score 0):

Reference [1.7 Declarations](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_chapter/indent_1.html#SEC10):

> If the ‘-bc’ option is specified, a newline is forced after each comma in a declaration. For example,

```
int a,
  b,
  c;
```

> With the ‘-nbc’ option this would look like

```
int a, b, c;
```

You need to use the `-nbc` option to get the output you want.

Note that this will disable newlines after every `,` in a declaration.

You may want to look at [1.10 Disabling Formatting](https://www.gnu.org/software/indent/manual/html_chapter/indent_1.html#SEC13) to turn off formating for a particular section of code.

For example:

```
void
foo ()
{
/* *INDENT-OFF* */
  struct_a arr[] = {
    {&a, sizeof (a)},
    {&b, sizeof (b)},
    {&c, sizeof (c)},
    {&d, sizeof (d)},
  };
/* *INDENT-ON* */
}
```

Comment: Just tried but `-nbc` does not work for me.

Comment: Did you try the Disabling Formatting option?

Comment: It's not practical for me to insert such Disabling Formating strings in our production code and I may need to run indent regularly.